# Can you compile C++ within a Python script?

Tags: python, c++, compilation

I'm VERY new to C++. I'm writing a Python script to compile and call a C++ program. The code:

```
system( "g++ -std=c++11 /home/my_program.cpp" )
system( "/home/a.out arg1" )
```

This seems to execute the C++ program just fine.

However, when I make changes to the C++ program and try running my pythons script, the changes don't seem to take effect. The output of the C++ code is still the same as it was before the changes.

Is it possible to compile C++ code in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That binary is going to drop in the working directory, not next to the C++ file. Add a `-o` argument to g++ to make sure it writes to the same place. When I try your example myself with the output option, it works just fine.

For a more literal interpretation of your question, check out cppyy:
https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```cpp
import cppyy
cppyy.cppdef(r'void say_hello() { std::cout << "Hello!\n"; }');
cppyy.gbl.say_hello()
```

Comment: I tried adding the `-o` option, and i got the error: **error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.**

Comment: It sounds like you're using a C++11 feature and compiling it in an older version of g++ where that standard isn't the default. Did you try adding the  `-std=c++11` flag recommended by the error message?

Comment: Yes, and the changes are still not being reflected. When I compile and run it using `-std=c++11` and not `-o` via the command line, it works as expected. It only doesn't work via the Python script

Comment: Does it still error, or it's just back to not reflecting in the binary? And can you share the exact commands in their current state?

Comment: Sorry, your initial answer was correct. I was looking at the wrong binary. I was confused because when I was compiling and running it via the command line, the binary was in the same location as the cpp file. Thanks so much!